# Forward photos without downloading them on whatsapp

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

How can i forward photos without downloading them on whatsapp?

Someone sent me many photos at once. There's no actions button next to the message. I click the blurred 4x4 photos grid and it opens a list of all of the blurred photos. How do I send them to someone else? The bottom-left action button is greyed out.

Comment: Don't see the Apple connection here... shouldn't you maybe ask this WhatsApp support?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I've been told to ask iOS app questions on this stack before...

Comment: Can‘t you run Whatsapp on a desktop machine and access the pictures from there?